# Scroll height in a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

[image]

As shown in the image, how can i find the scrolled height relative to  DIV not to window

> Edit

Uploaded another image for more clearity

Comment: Have you looked at http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/ ?

Comment: it tells position with respect to window

Comment: Only if you use it on the window. From the docs: "Description: Get the current vertical position of the scroll bar for the first _element_ in the set of matched elements." Look at the second example on the documentation.

Comment: `$("div.demo").scrollTop(300);` this code tell scrollPositon with respect to window.

Comment: Really? You're going to tell me that this example (http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/x5fbS/) is scrolling from the top of the window and not the div?

Comment: this is not working for me and iam not looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.position()` instead of `.offset()`. That's the offset relative to the parent. (in jQuery of course)

[documentation](http://api.jquery.com/position/)

I'm actually not sure if this is what you are looking for...

Answer (score 0):

may be try to find `div` position and than set your body in `document.ready`

```
 var position = $("divid").offset().top;
 $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: position },'slow');
```

Hops its helps